# REST in Wordpress 4.7

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-4.7

I currently working on wordpress 4.7. I want to deliver photo and text(JSON) through REST. In wordpress 4.6, I used WP REST API plugin and it's great. But I hear that on wordpress 4.7 WP REST API has been included in the wordpress core function, so we don't need to install the plugin. My question is how do we use it? I didn't find the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can read the official documentation at the [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer as the OP asked how to use it not where the documentation was.  Granted, it's bad the OP couldn't figure out the documentation location from a simple Google search.